# Effect of Unbind application in TFS on server

Tags: tfs

If I Unbind a web application from source control in Visual Studio 2010, will it have any effect on the TFS server at all?  i.e. Log an unbind, etc.

While I have been able to find many resources on the "how" to do this (unbind), I can find none on what is being done under the covers by the GUI selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say categorically what it does for web apps, but as far as I know for C++/C# solutions it saves a source control information file (`SolutionName.vssssc` file or similar) next to your solution to record the bindings in.

I think the bindings are just a map of where projects are stored in TFS and on your PC so they can be found and related to each other when you are online - so I believe they are local to your PC and nothing happens server-side when you bind/unbind.

It's possible that there is a difference for a web project. It's also possible that my many assumptions about the bindings (which are based purely on observation of their behaviour over many years) are completely wrong, so please take all the above with a pinch of salt :-)

Comment: I performed a test to verify that this answer is correct, and at least as far as the history in tfs, it is.  Unbind action is totally a client action.